# exclude admin archive edit screen

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I need to exclude some code from executing on this admin page

```
wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=properties
```

But i need it to run on this admin page which is the admin page for all single properties

```
wp-admin/post.php?post=210&action=edit
```

I tried this code and other snippets like it but it doesn't work :

```
if ( 'post.php' === $pagenow && 'post' === get_post_type( $_GET['post'] ) )
```

The problem is the code is duplicating data on the admin archive

[image]

Edit : This is the code i need to conditionally execute

```
 function load_metabox() {
        include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/form.php' );
    }
```

Comment: on which hook do you use this code ?

Comment: admin_menu add_meta_box

Comment: the file `edit.php` doesn't use metaboxes. edit your question to give more details about the code you use.

Comment: @mmm The 2nd parameter for admin_menu is a function and that function uses add_meta_box which is very common.